# Display Local HTML file from documents directory in a UIWebView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, uiwebview, documents

How can I display a HTML file from the Documents directory in my app?
Below is the code that I'm using and nothing is showing up in my `UIWebView`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"Notes.html"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [notesListWeb loadRequest:request];
```

Why is this not working out?

I've found other answers but they aren't from the documents directory.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to log the `filePath`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to create an **NSURL** object with a file path is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```

You should also change how you create your *filePath*:

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notes.html"];
```

Also keep in mind that filenames are case sensitive on a real iOS device. Is the file really named Notes.html and notes.html?