# load html file to UIWebview from documents directory on ios with swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview, ios-simulator

I have an html file and other files that html uses(css,.png) that is saved in the documents directory.How can I load this html file in a UIWebView or wkwebview
using swift?I have found some examples in objective-c but nothing in swift.I don't know anything about objective-c..

```
let path=getCurrenttHtmlStartPage()
var hContent = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) 
webView!.loadHTMLString(hContent, baseURL: nil)
webView!.hidden=false
```

Path is the path in documents folder. /Users/pmdevios/Library/.../Documents/Content/Html/index.html.

With this way the other files inside html aren't showing(images) so I want to do it with another way like this

```
webView!.loadFileURL(path, allowingReadAccessToURL: path)
```

Comment: can you please post your code here..

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647447/load-local-html-into-uiwebview-using-swift

Comment: @NimitParekh So far I have only this: 'let path=getCurrenttHtmlStartPage()
            var hContent = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            webView!.loadHTMLString(hContent, baseURL: nil)
            webView!.hidden=false ' .  path is the path in documents folder (/Users/pmdevios/Library/.../Documents/Content/Html/index.html) .With this way the other files inside html aren't showing(images) so I want to do it with another way like this 'webView!.loadFileURL(path, allowingReadAccessToURL: path)'    or wit a NSUrlRequest but i cannot make it work.

Comment: @Igor it is not duplicate what I'm asking is load from Documents directory a file that is download in runtime and not from application resources!

Comment: @Nimit Parekh it's the same only difference - how to build the path, and this  question is very well documented by apple

Comment: @solero_ice have use image into html file?

Comment: @NimitParekh yes.Also i have found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984502/display-local-html-file-from-documents-directory-in-a-uiwebview-on-iphone that might be the answer but is in objective-c and i have trouble with this.

Comment: @solero_ice Can you post your html code here.

Comment: @NimitParekh  it is something simple.here http://pastebin.com/Pg0jVkZe

Comment: @solero_ice I need to debug your code if you have code can you please send it to me.

Comment: @NimitParekh thanks but i make it work.Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

With the below code it worked!

```
let filePath = (folder as  NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(_currentHtmlStartPage!)
var url:NSURL=NSURL(fileURLWithPath:filePath)
var request:NSURLRequest=NSURLRequest(URL:url)
webView!.loadRequest(request)
```

folder:string that represents the path in the documents folder
_currentHtmlStartPage:string of file's name (e.g. index.html)

Answer (score 1):

---

EDIT

1. Get URL using NSFileManger instance method  [`URLsForDirectory(inDomains:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory:inDomains:)
2. Append the file name (myFile.html) to the URL we get back from NSFileManager
3. Initialize a [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/) object with the URL.
4. Use the [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/) or [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/loadRequest:) class to load the request.

---

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var URL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
URL = URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myFile.html")

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: fileURL)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I have edited my answer to include an explanation of the code. Appreciate the link and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head:

```
if let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myFile", withExtension: "html") {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: fileURL)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

You'll need a flat directory structure in your html and css files because that's how they end up in the app.

Comment: what I'm asking is load from Documents directory a file that is download in runtime and not from application resources

Comment: The principle is the same more or less.